# Shell script to copy directory structure based on a condition

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I have an specific requirement and I need your help in writing shell script.

1. The script should copy the directory structure from source path to target path preserving permission, timestamps etc.
2. The script should copy only text files from only those sub-directories under which there are no more sub-directories.

This is what i have done so far.

```
    #!/bin/bash

    source_exist=false

    while true
    do
        echo -n "Enter source path:"
        read source

    if [ ! -d $source ] 
    then
        echo "$source is not a valid directory!!!"
        echo -n "Try Again [Y/N]"
        read result
        if [ $result = 'Y' -o $result = 'y' ]  
        then
            continue
        else
            exit 1;
        fi
    else
        source_exist=true
        break;
    fi
done
echo -n "enter target path:"
read target
if [ source_exist ]
then
mkdir $target
fi
find $source '*.txt' -exec cp -p --parents \{\} $target \;
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read the guidelines for asking questions properly. In short, this is place where you show us what you have done so far (your code) and we try to help you from where you are stuck.

Comment: @user3322633 Please share your code what you have so far.

Comment: How are you supposed to determine which files are text files?  By extension, or by content?  The 'leaf-directories' requirement is moderately interesting.  Do you have to deal with awkward-squad file names (names containing outré punctuation or spaces or newlines), or are the names all civilized (portable filename character set: A-Za-z0-9_ plus dot and dash)?

Comment: by extension with .txt

Comment: friends, I am a beginer in shell scripting. therefore couldn't do much. I googled a lot but couldn't find the solution.

Comment: assuming all file names to be civilized

Comment: Have you considered using rsync ?

Comment: @Bolli I don't know the usage of rsync

Comment: I have found one more script to get leaf directory:
find . -type d -exec sh -c '(ls -p "{}"|grep />/dev/null)||echo "{}"' \;

Comment: Run this through http://shellcheck.net/ and fix all the issues it finds before asking here. Also follow the rules at http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, and isolate the smallest possible thing that's wrong, rather than posting the whole script.

Comment: Anything that suggests using `ls -p` programatically, by the way, is extremely poor advice. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: Also, using `-o` or `-a` inside of test constructs is officially deprecated by the POSIX standard; see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html

Comment: "Assuming names to be civilized" is **extremely** bad practice -- that's writing your code in such a way as to **know** it has bugs. Why not write it the right way, and not have to worry? I've been at a job where we had TB of billing records accidentally deleted because of code that assumed all names would match `[0-9a-f]{24}`... and then a bug dumped random garbage from memory into a filename containing a whitespace-surrounded asterisk, and a buggy rotation script tried to delete that file.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I have done:

- First I am copying the whole directory structure as it is without copying any files.
- Then I search for leaf directory in source folder and write them to a file leafs.txt
- Then I search for leaf directory in target folder and write them to another file leafd.txt
- Since both the directory structure are same hence the output comes same in both the text files with just a name of change of starting directory.
- Then I read both the files simultaneously line by line and copy text files from source path line from leafs.txt to the target path line from leafd.txt.
- The source directory name is given by the user and the target directory is created by the script with the name as the system date.
- Finally both the temp files leafs.txt and leafd.txt are removed.

Also a log fine is generated with name as system date showing which files are copied from which source directory to which target directory preserving permission, timestamp etc.

Here is the code:

```
1  #!/bin/bash
   2  
   3  source_exist=false
   4  
   5  while true
   6  do
   7      #Read source path
   8      echo -n "Enter source path:"
   9      read -r source
  10  
  11      #If source is not a Direcotry
  12      if [ ! -d "$source" ] 
  13      then
  14          echo "$source is not a valid directory!!!"
  15          echo -n "Try Again [Y/N]"
  16          read -r result
  17          if [ $result = "Y" -o $result = "y" ]  
  18          then
  19              continue
  20          else
  21              exit 1;
  22          fi
  23      else
  24          source_exist=true
  25          break;
  26      fi
  27      done
  28  
  29      target=$(date +%F)
  30      touch $target.txt
  31  
  32      if [ source_exist ]
  33      then
  34          #create target directory
  35          mkdir -p $target
  36      fi
  37      #copy source direcotry structure only to the target
  38      find $source -type d -printf "$target/%P\0" | xargs -0 mkdir -p
  39  
  40      #find leaf directories in source and write them to a file   
  41      find $source -depth -type d | while read dir;  do [[ ! $prev =~ $dir ]] && echo "${dir}" ; prev="$dir"; done > leafs.txt
  42      #find leaf directories in target and write them to a file   
  43      find $target -depth -type d | while read dir;  do [[ ! $prev =~ $dir ]] && echo "${dir}" ; prev="$dir"; done > leafd.txt
  44      file1='leafs.txt'
  45      file2='leafd.txt'
  46      #read both the files simultaneously line by line and copy all .text file from source to destination
  47      while IFS= read -r lineA && IFS= read -r lineB <&3; 
  48      do
  49  
  50      #copy files preserving permission, timestamp etc. 
  51      cp --preserve -v "$lineA"/*.txt "$lineB" 2>/dev/null >> $target.txt
  52  
  53  
  54      done <$file1 3<$file2
  55      #remove the created text files  
  56      rm leafs.txt
  57      rm leafd.txt
  58      exit 0
```